# Storing PHP Simple HTML DOM results to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dom

I'm trying to take parsed data and store it to a DB. With the way it is currently setup, it only stores the first item on the referenced website in the database. I need it to loop through and save each item to a row in the table. Where do I need to make modifications in my code?

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.hiddenurl.com/whatever/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach ($html->find('li.search-result') as $sitelisting)
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "mypasshere");
if (!$con) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dataminer", $con);

$debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO extract (listing) 
VALUES ('$sitelisting')");
if (!$debugquery) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You forgot `{}` after foreach, right now it's just opening as many new connections to the database as there are items in your listing...

Comment: Do not use mysql_* it is depricated use mysqli_ or PDO instead!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.hiddenurl.com/whatever/');

// Find all article blocks

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "mypasshere");
mysql_select_db("dataminer", $con);
if (!$con) {
    die(mysql_error());
} else {
    foreach ($html->find('li.search-result') as $sitelisting) {

        $debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO extract (listing) VALUES ('$sitelisting')");
        if (!$debugquery) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

EDIT:
for this `‘` use  `&lsquo;`
for this `’` use `&rsquo;`

EDIT2:

```
$debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO extract (listing) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sitelisting)."') ");
```

Comment: For security reasons, you should probably check out the new `mysqli` functions that are equivalent to the `mysql` functions your using here. `mysql` functions are deprecated.

Comment: This somewhat works but is giving me an error when there is an apostrophe in the HTML content. What do I need to do to escape the apostrophe properly?

Comment: goodmood: There's apostrophes in the content of the website I'm scraping.

Comment: look if this what u need in my update. just replace apostrof by the code i writed

Comment: or maybe you mean this normal apostrof `'` ? if not that , pls give me this line where there is apostrof

Comment: I'm referring to the mysql_query() portion. The scraped content has 's so when inserting into the table, I am getting errors when it gets to the 's in the parsed HTML content.

Comment: can u write this this content ?

Comment: I basically need to know how I would use mysql_real_escape_string() with this.

Comment: if you have variable `$var` do it like that `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help.